# <Select> keeps reseting on submit

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make an contact form for my website and I am using the following code. I don't know why the selector keeps reseting when the text fields don't.

Anyone know a soultion for this? Or what I am doing wrong.

( It resets when the error check is done, and fails )

```html
<?php
session_start();
$php_self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

// on submit
if( isset($_POST[name]) && isset($_POST[email]) && isset($_POST[message]) && isset($_POST[captcha]) ){
    $name = $_POST[name];
    $email = $_POST[email];
 $telefon = $_POST[telefon];
 $option = $_POST[option];
    $message = $_POST[message];
    $captcha = $_POST[captcha];
     
    $error = 0;
    // name
    if( $name == "" ){ $error ++; $error_name = "class='error'"; }
    // email
    if( $email == "" ){ $error ++; $error_email = "class='error'"; }
    // message
    if( $message == "" ){ $error ++; $error_message = "class='error'"; }
    // captcha
    if( $captcha == "" || $captcha != $_SESSION[captcha]){ $error ++; $error_captcha = "class='error'"; }
 
    // no error, send email
    if( $error == 0){               
                         
        // your email address
        $address = "surrealcmstest@outlook.com";
         
        // email subject
        $subject = "x , Nytt Meddelande \r\n";
        // email content
        $content = "Namn: $name \r\nE-postadress: $email \r\nTelefon Nr: $telefon \r\nKontakta mig via: $option \r\nMeddelande: $message";
        // html email
        $email_content = "".$subject."";
        $email_content .= "";
        $email_content .= $content;
        $email_content .= "";                     
                 

        // send email
        mail($address, $subject, $email_content, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");         
         
        // reset variables
        $name = ""; $email = ""; $message = "";
        $mail_sent = 1;                                                             
    }
}
 
// captcha
$num = rand(1, 20);
$num2 = rand(1, 9);     
$verif = $num . " + " . $num2;
$_SESSION[captcha] = $num + $num2;      
 
if( $mail_sent == 1 ){
    echo "<div class=","sucess",">Ditt meddelande har skickats, vi återkommer så fort som möjligt.</div>";
} else {
    echo "
    <form action='".$php_self."' method='post'>
 <p><span class='required'>* är obligatoriska fält.</span></p>
    <p><strong>Namn:</strong> <span class='required'>*</span></p>
    <input type='text' ".$error_name." name='name' value='".$name."'>
    <p><strong>E-postadress:</strong> <span class='required'>*</span></p>
    <input type='email' ".$error_email." name='email' value='".$email."'>
 <p><strong>Telefon Nr:</strong></p>
    <input type='telefon' name='telefon' value='".$telefon."'>
 <p><strong>Kontakta mig via:</strong></p>
 <select name='option'>
 <option value='-'>-</option>
 <option value='Telefon'>Telefon</option>
 <option value='E-post'>E-post</option>
 </select>
    <p><strong>Meddelande:</strong> <span class='required'>*</span></p>
    <textarea ".$error_message." name='message'>".$message."</textarea>
    <p><strong>Hur mycket är ".$verif."?</strong> <span class='required'>*</span></p>            
    <input type='text' ".$error_captcha." name='captcha' value=''><br/>
    <button>Skicka</button>
    </form>";
}
?>
```

Comment: why `$_POST['option']` is not included in this line `if( isset($_POST[name]) && isset($_POST[email]) && isset($_POST[message]) && isset($_POST[captcha]) ){` ?

Comment: Just an FYI, don't use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for forms like this. It is insecure and makes it easy to inject code (javascript) to the source of your page through the URL. If you wanted to submit the form to the same page, just leave the action blank. That is the default behavior.

Comment: added the line, keeps reseting :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a check for each `option` Tag like you do with the inputs and load from the $_POST value before...

```
$option = $_POST['option'];
```

And in the select

```
<select name='option'>
    <option value='-'>-</option>
    <option value='Telefon' ".($option == 'Telefon' ? "selected":"").">Telefon</option>
    <option value='E-post' ".($option == 'E-post'? "selected" : "").">E-post</option>
</select>
```

### Edited:

Changed it to the inline string statement for the output string that the OP is generating...

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Oh you are echoing the whole select as a string.  Try the new edited version now.